# Is the sum of conditionally independent random variables independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let's say I have three random variables $X,Y,Z$ such that  $X$ is independent of $Z$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$.

Is it true that $X+Y$ is independent of $Z$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

The classical example is to take $X,Y$ independent Bernoulli$(1/2)$ random variables (uniformly distributed on $\{0,1\}$), and set $Z\stackrel{\rm def}{=}X+Y \bmod 2$.

$X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent (more than what you ask), yet $X+Y$ is clearly not independent of $Z$.

Comment: I didn't know about the \bmod command. Thanks!

Comment: For several seconds I was tempted to answer "yes" and then realized that when I looked at it rigorously it was a lot harder to prove than I thought.  Once as an undergraduate I wondered why I had trouble coming up with a routine $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof that if $f$ is differentiable on some interval containing $a$ and $f'(a)$ is positive then $f$ is increasing on some (posisbly smaller) interval containing $a$. Then I found a similar reason why that was harder than I thought!  If pairwise independence had been asked about I'd have thought of this example immediately. $\qquad$

Comment: The "b" stands for "binary" and it means that this "mod" is formatted according to the conventions for binary operators (such as a plus sign). $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, the spacing of $\mod 2$ always bugged me, I never realized it was simply because it was not the right operator for what I was trying to do...